# How to remove whitespace between ::before and actual content

Tags: html, css, html-lists, pseudo-element

I want to create a custom numbering style for an ordered list that immitates footnotes.
However, when I do this, via an `li::before` pseudoelement (see snippet below), if there is a whitespace between the `<li>` tag and its actual content in the HTML code, there is a space rendered between the custom number and the item content.

What do I have to do to get rid of the whitespace, or at least make it behave consistently (i.e. it always is or is not there), regardless of whether there is one in the HTML code?

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: x;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: x;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(x);
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>no leading space</li>
  <li>
    leading space
  </li>
<ol>
```

Comment: That white-space is caused by including a line-break. SO you actually hardcoded it in as content. There is no trick then not to include a space in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Let's normalize it to be with white space. For all the good reasons. This is done by adding `" "` to the counter(x) content.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: x;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: x;
}

ol li::before {
  content: " " counter(x) " ";
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>no leading space</li>
  <li>
    leading space
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Picking up on @IT goldman's answer: If you don't want that "normalized" space, you could still do it that way, but add `position: relative;` and a *negative* `right`setting to the `ol li::before` rule to move the number towards the beginning of the `li` contents:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: x;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: x;
}

ol li::before {
  content: " " counter(x) " ";
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: smaller;
  position: relative;
  right: -0.2em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>no leading space</li>
  <li>
    leading space
  </li>
</ol>
```